# Rigid body corners

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

[image: Corners]I don't know how to call this problem but while I'm simulating rigid body physics I noticed that as the cube falls and hits the corner of a block (especially when the cube is high) it merge some part of cube as it bounces back

Could this be fixed?

Comment: maybe try other settings, like Mesh instead of Box, then increase the Sensitivity Margin?

Comment: @moonboots I tried changing it to mesh but it doesn't act like a box, I also tried adjusting the sensitivity even in smallest difference but its either the same result or there is a visible gap in between.